# Write out file with google colab

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Was there a way to write out files with google colab?
For example, if I use

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
```

Where will those files be stored? Can they be found?
And similarly, can I get the file I outputted via say tensorflow save function

```
saver=tf.Saver(....)
...
path = saver.save(sess, "./my_model.ckpt")
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's a colab notebook on different ways to handle I/O, check it out: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Comment: @DanielLenz Thanks! I didn't pay attention to those intro files. Dumb me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your first example, the data is still in `r.content`. So you also need to save them first with `open('data.dat', 'wb').write(r.content)`

Then you can download them with `files.download`

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('data.dat')
```

Downloading your model is the same:

```
files.download('my_model.ckpt')
```

Answer (score 4):

I found it is easier to first mount your Google drive to the non-persistent VM and then use `os.chdir()` to change your current working folder.

After doing this, you can do the exactly same stuff as in local machine.

I have a gist listing several ways to save and transfer files between Colab VM and Google drive, but I think mounting Google drive is the easiest approach.

For more details, please refer to `mount_your_google_drive.md` in this gist
https://gist.github.com/Joshua1989/dc7e60aa487430ea704a8cb3f2c5d6a6