# Restore Tensorflow Model Failed in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Restoring tensorflow model using saver.restore(sess,model_dir) is failing in Google Colaboratory.

**Restore Code**

```
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    sq_net = classifierNet(input_shape,out_classes,lr_rate,is_train)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        train_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
        if model_dir is not None:
                 if os.path.exists("{}.index".format(model_dir)):
                        saver = tf.train.Saver()
                        saver.restore(sess, model_dir)
                        print("Model at %s restored" % model_dir)
                 else:
                        print("Model path does not exist, skipping...")
        else:
                 print("Model path is None - Nothing to restore")
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from dri//colab//mod//
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
    1360   def _register_dead_handle(self, handle):
    -> 1361     # Register a dead handle in the session. Delete the dead tensors when
    1362     # the number of dead tensors exceeds certain threshold.

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
    1339     # Nothing to do if we're using the new session interface
    -> 1340     # TODO(skyewm): remove this function altogether eventually
    1341     if self._created_with_new_api: return

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)

   NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for dri//colab//mod//model.ckpt
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-fb31e76f6b17> in <module>()
     11           if os.path.exists("{}.index".format(model_dir)):
     12               saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=v0_vars)
---> 13               saver.restore(sess, model_dir)
     14               print("Model at %s restored" % model_dir)
     15           else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
   1753   # Create a saver.
   1754   saver = tf.train.Saver(...variables...)
-> 1755   # Remember the training_op we want to run by adding it to a collection.
   1756   tf.add_to_collection('train_op', train_op)
   1757   sess = tf.Session()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    903     This is EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change.
    904 
--> 905     To use partial execution, a user first calls `partial_run_setup()` and
    906     then a sequence of `partial_run()`. `partial_run_setup` specifies the
    907     list of feeds and fetches that will be used in the subsequent

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1135     convertible to an ndarray) with matching element type and shape. See
   1136     @{tf.Session.run} for details of the allowable feed key and value types.
-> 1137 
   1138     The returned callable will have the same return type as
   1139     `tf.Session.run(fetches, ...)`. For example, if `fetches` is a `tf.Tensor`,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1353           tf_session.TF_ExtendGraph(
   1354               self._session, graph_def.SerializeToString(), status)
-> 1355         self._opened = True
   1356 
   1357   # The threshold to run garbage collection to delete dead tensors.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1372       fetches = []
   1373       for deleter_key, tensor_handle in enumerate(tensors_to_delete):
-> 1374         holder, deleter = session_ops._get_handle_deleter(self.graph,
   1375                                                           deleter_key,
   1376                                                           tensor_handle)

NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for dri//colab//mod//model.ckpt
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-44-fb31e76f6b17>", line 12, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=v0_vars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1293, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1302, in build
    """
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1339, in _build
    """Deletes old checkpoints if necessary.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 796, in _build_internal
    RuntimeError: If the SAVERS collection already has more than one items.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 449, in _AddRestoreOps
    filename_tensor: Tensor for the path of the file to load.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 847, in bulk_restore
    if all_model_checkpoint_paths is None:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1030, in restore_v2
    shape_and_slices = _ops.convert_to_tensor(shape_and_slices, _dtypes.string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    # Just being a bit paranoid here

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for dri//colab//mod//model.ckpt
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Mounting Drive Code:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
# Generate auth tokens for Colab
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
# Generate creds for the Drive FUSE library.
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
!mkdir -p dri
!google-drive-ocamlfuse dri
```

After training my model on Google Colab, I want to save it and then restore it for testing purposes. I am able to save the model but the restore function throws the above error in Google Colab (This is working on my local machine though). Please suggest the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is that `saver.restore(model_dir)` cannot find `model_dir` which is  `dri//colab//mod//model.ckpt`. You can check the contents of this directory by executing say `!ls -l dri//colab//mod//` to make sure you model is there. You can get your model into the colab environment in various ways, e.g. checkout https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb. You can also mount your google drive on your local machine and read/write to it. See second answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675374/write-out-file-with-google-colab

Comment: Thanks Iga. I have mounted my drive and then saved the model to that location. After saving, the model is present in my google drive. I have edited the question with code used for mounting. On reading the model through the mount using the restore function it shows the not found error. Please suggest changes.

Comment: Do you see your files through colab (e.g. run `!ls -l dri//colab//mod//`)? Can somebody in the middle be unhappy about double slashes (please remove them)? Maybe you need a slash at the beginning of your path? I am not expert in this, but it seems like something basic is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. On using that ls command I saw that it is not able to see all the other files but only checkpoint file. Now I first download the files to colab using file id and then it works. Thanks a lot Iga.

Answer (score 0):

Download the model files into colab using the file id. Follow this - https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb.